# web.py - Is it possible to pass parameters from template to the script?

Tags: templates, web.py

Is it possible to pass parameters from template back to the script ?

In example I have a page add.html with a few input fields like Name, Last name.

```
<input type="text" name="name" size="50" />
<input type="text" name="last_name" size="50" />
```

In addition, I have secret key (just an example, remember? :)):
    $ secret_key = random.randint(0,10)

Can I pass secret_key and get it via web.input inside script? 
Something like that maybe?:
main.py:

```
def add(self):
    def POST(self):
        post_sent = web.input()
        secret_key = post_sent['secret_key'] # extracted from template
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="secret_key" value="$random.randint(0,10)" />
```